# Changing the selected object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

What I am trying to do is rewrite content on the page depending on which object I have selected. I have some objects like so:

```
function floorPlan(name,rev,sqft,bedrm,bthrm) {
this.name = name;
this.rev = rev;
this.sqft = sqft;
this.bedrm = bedrm;
this.bthrm = bthrm;
}

// 1BR Plans

var a1 = new floorPlan('A1',false,557,1,1);
var a2 = new floorPlan('A2',false,652,1,1);
var a3 = new floorPlan('A3',false,654,1,1);
var a4 = new floorPlan('A4',false,705,1,1);
var a5 = new floorPlan('A5',false,788,1,1);

// The Selected plan

var currentPlan = floorPlan.a1;
```

I am having the user control this via a `.click()` function in a menu:

```
$('.sideNav li').click(function() {

  // Define the currentPlan
  var current = $(this).attr('id');
  var currentPlan = floorPlan.current;

});
```

The problem is that `currentPlan` keeps coming back as undefined and I have no idea why. Should I be defining `currentPlan` differently? I can't seem to find any resources to help me find the answer.

---

UPDATED:

I switched out a few parts per your suggestions:

```
// The Selected plan

var currentPlan = a1;
```

and....

```
// Define the currentPlan

var current = $(this).attr('id');

currentPlan = current;
```

However, everything is still returning undefined in the click function (not initially though).

Comment: Shouldn't that simply be currentPlan = a1; ?

Comment: `floorPlan.current` isn't defined anywhere, hence it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all $('this') should be $(this)

Secondly you're trying to use a read ID from your LI as a variable name. That doesn't work. If you store your plans in an array you can use the ID to search in that array:

```
var plans=Array();
plans["a1"]=new floorPlan('A1',false,557,1,1);
plans["a2"]=new floorPlan('A2',false,652,1,1);
```

Then your jQuery code should be altered to this:

```
$('.sideNav li').click(function() {
  // Define the currentPlan
  var current = $(this).attr('id');
  var currentPlan = plans[current];

  alert(currentPlan);        
});
```

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4Prx/) for this. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Edited the answer to what I think it is you're looking for.

Comment: You sir, are simply amazing. Could you explain why storing the ID in an array solves the problem? I am interested to learn how that does the trick.

Comment: You're getting the ID from your LI with $(this).attr("id"). That ID is a string, not a variable name. So if you do "currentPlan=current" you put the string in currentPlan, not the variable with the same name. Using an array uses the string you got as an index. In that case a string can be used nicely

Answer (score 1):

Use as floorPlan.currentPlan = a1;

instead of var currentPlan = floorPlan.a1;

Please create a plunker and will correct if any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I spot two errors.

When you write `var` inside a function, that variable is only accessible with that function. Right now you are creating a new variable in your anonymous function that is "hiding" the global variable with the same name.

So, first remove the `var` keyword from the assignment in the anonymous function (the one you call on "click").

Secondly I think you mean to assign `floorPlan[current]`.

The final line should read:

`currentPlan = floorPlan[current];`